# Deny IP access to an inside Tomcat directory

Tags: tomcat7, security, tomcat-valve

I'm trying to solve the following:

I have a Tomcat web application which is configured (and should be) to accept ANY IP. 
e.g: (protocol://host:port/MyApp/)

What I want to do is to only allow certain IP's to enter a directory stored inside my web app AND when entering, being prompted a username and password. 
e.g:(protocol://host:port/MyApp/Directory)

I think the configuration should be done in context.xml and/or web.xml but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can star from the following links

1. How to add security to your Web Application: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html
2. How to deny access based on IP or host:
   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter
   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Host_Filter